# Spring Jersey Web App - Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jersey

I need some help here after a few days of trying to learn spring I have  given up trying to find a decent resource.

I am making a Web Application and this is my first full application and I want to use Jersey to make it and also use Spring . I am Using eclipse IDE and Maven as a build tool.

With these settings how is the best way to set up such a web application. Ie the application context ect also do i need to configure some sort of container to run the application on the server as with working with some examples they run fine locally but not on deployment.

If anyone has any tutorials that they have used or infact any resources they are greatly appreciated, Ideally want to have an application set up that uses simpleJDBCtemplate and i can then just code my backend implementation into it.

Help!
Thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the source code given at http://gitorious.org/java-rest-example was very helpful in getting a Jersey app up and running quickly. It uses Jetty, which I've found to be a fast, lightweight web app container. That example doesn't use Spring, but for a basic REST application, you might not need it.

As for a Spring resource, I bought the book [Spring Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://apress.com/book/view/1590599799)
and found it helpful for explaining Spring from the ground up. One thing I liked about it is it shows you the simple/naive ways of achieving something followed by more sophisticated/cleaner ways of doing things.